# CoreBluetooth CBCentralManager unwraps as nil even when unwrapped from the stateUpdateHandler's case .poweredOn. Any idea why?

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

CBCentralManager unwraps as nil even if accessed in the stateUpdateHandler on .poweredOn.  If I put a sleep(1) before accessing CBCentralManager, there's no problem.  Why is this happening?  If it's .poweredOn surely there's a non-nil instance there already?

The following code worked until upgrading my OS to Catalina and Xcode to 11.5.

```
extension BLEController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager)  {
        switch central.state {
        case .unknown:
            print("central.state is .unknown")
        case .resetting:
            print("central.state is .resetting")
        case .unsupported:
            print("central.state is .unsupported")
        case .unauthorized:
            print("central.state is .unauthorized")
        case .poweredOff:
            print("central.state is .poweredOff")
        case .poweredOn:
            print("Bluetooth module is on.  Searching...")

            sleep(1)  // works fine if this is here, but if .poweredOn it should be non-nil?

            // unwraps as nil
            guard let cManager = centralManager else {
                print("centralManager is nil")
                return
            }

            cManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [self.heartRateServiceCBUUID])

        @unknown default:
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Full code:

```
import Foundation
import CoreBluetooth





class BLEController: CBCentralManager {

    var btQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "BT Queue")

    var bpmReceived: ((Int) -> Void)?

    var bpm: Int? {
        didSet {
            self.bpmReceived?(self.bpm!)
        }
    }


    var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    var heartRatePeripheral: CBPeripheral!

    let heartRateServiceCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "0x180D")

    let heartRateMeasurementCharacteristicCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "2A37")
    let batteryLevelCharacteristicCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "2A19")



    func start() -> Void {
        print("bluetooth started")
        self.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: self.btQueue)
    }


    func stop() -> Void {
        centralManager.cancelPeripheralConnection(heartRatePeripheral)
    }


    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager,
                        didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                        advertisementData: [String: Any],
                        rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

        heartRatePeripheral = peripheral
        heartRatePeripheral.delegate = self
        centralManager.stopScan()
        centralManager.connect(heartRatePeripheral)
    }



    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager,
                        didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print("Connected to HRM!")
        heartRatePeripheral.discoverServices(nil)
    }


    func onHeartRateReceived(_ heartRate: Int) {
        self.bpm = heartRate
    }
}



extension BLEController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager)  {
        switch central.state {
        case .unknown:
            print("central.state is .unknown")
        case .resetting:
            print("central.state is .resetting")
        case .unsupported:
            print("central.state is .unsupported")
        case .unauthorized:
            print("central.state is .unauthorized")
        case .poweredOff:
            print("central.state is .poweredOff")
        case .poweredOn:
            print("Bluetooth module is on.  Searching...")

            sleep(1)  // works fine if this is here, but if .poweredOn it should be non-nil?

            // unwraps as nil
            guard let cManager = centralManager else {
                print("centralManager is nil")
                return
            }

            cManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [self.heartRateServiceCBUUID])

        @unknown default:
            return
        }
    }
}



extension BLEController: CBPeripheralDelegate {
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        guard let services = peripheral.services else { return }

        for service in services {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
        }
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else { return }

        for characteristic in characteristics {
            if characteristic.properties.contains(.read) {
                peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
            }
            if characteristic.properties.contains(.notify) {
                peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
            }
        }
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic,
                    error: Error?) {
        switch characteristic.uuid {
        case batteryLevelCharacteristicCBUUID:
            let percent = batteryLevel(from: characteristic)
            print("Battery level: \(percent)%")
        case heartRateMeasurementCharacteristicCBUUID:
            let bpm = heartRate(from: characteristic)
            onHeartRateReceived(bpm)
        default:
            return
        }
    }

    private func heartRate(from characteristic: CBCharacteristic) -> Int {
        guard let characteristicData = characteristic.value else { return -1 }
        let byteArray = [UInt8](characteristicData)

        let firstBitValue = byteArray[0] & 0x01
        if firstBitValue == 0 {
            // Heart Rate Value Format is in the 2nd byte
            return Int(byteArray[1])
        } else {
            // Heart Rate Value Format is in the 2nd and 3rd bytes
            return (Int(byteArray[1]) << 8) + Int(byteArray[2])
        }
    }


    private func batteryLevel(from characteristic: CBCharacteristic) -> Int {
        guard let characteristicData = characteristic.value else { return -1 }
        let byteArray = [UInt8](characteristicData)
        return Int(byteArray[0])
    }

}
```

Comment: What is `centralManager`? An instance variable? Where, when and how is it initialized? Or should it be the parameter `central`?

Comment: I've just added the full code for context.  centralManager is an instance variable created when start() is called.  Once initialized, the delegate handles the state updates.  It used to progress from state .poweredOff to .poweredOn, but now when it is initialized, it begins with .poweredOn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant code is:

```
 self.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: self.btQueue)
```

and:

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager)  {
    switch central.state {
        ...
    case .poweredOn:
        ...
}
```

The call of the `CBCentralManager` initializer starts the action. You have to assume that the delegate will be immediately called from the initializer, i.e. the second piece of code is run before the initializer has returned and before the result has been assigned to the instance variable `centralManager`.

This will probably always happen if the Bluetooth device is already powered on when the initializer is called. If it isn't powered on yet, the delegate will be called later.

Anyway, you shouldn't need to worry about it. Instead of:

```
guard let cManager = centralManager else {
    print("centralManager is nil")
    return
}

cManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [self.heartRateServiceCBUUID])
```

just use:

```
central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [self.heartRateServiceCBUUID])
```

Within the delegate, the `CBCentralManager` instance is available as it is passed as a parameter.

Comment: I see, thank you so much for the detailed explanation!  It makes much more sense now!